# Difference between setBounds(x,y,width,height) and setBounds(new Rectangle(x,y,width,height))

Tags: java, swing, awt

Is it possible that when we use Java's `setBounds(x,y,width,height)` method, the component can change from place to place if we change the machine(monitor of different sizes or any multiple size display device) and `setBounds(new Rectangle(x,y,width,height))` method doesn't suffer from the same problem.
If what I am saying is correct, can somebody help to understand this?

Comment: Do you mean `setBounds` on a `JFrame`, specifically? In any case, both methods should have the *same* behavior. (Of course, unless one of the methods is overridden in a confusing way...)

Comment: In one of my project i used setBounds(x,y,width,height) for setting the swing components on JFrame. The UI was Exactly the same as I was expecting. But I tried to run the same code on different machine and i noticed that components was not taking place as they were on my local(on my laptop).  So does setBounds(new Rectangle(x,y,width,height)) method solves this issue?

Comment: Most likely: No, the methods should do the same. **But** when you are positioning your components **in** another component by using `setBounds`, then the behavior is not surprising. You should use a `LayoutManager`. The size of components may be different on different operating systems (e.g. the space that is available in a `JFrame` will depend on the size of the title bar, etc.)

Comment: *"Is it possible that when we use Java's `setBounds(x,y,width,height)` method, the component can change from place to place if we change the machine(monitor of different sizes or any multiple size display device).."*  Umm.. adapting to different screen conditions is exactly what **Java Layout Managers** were designed for. Learn to use them and you will see how they do just what is needed. See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: If I had a 2nd chance to vote to close this, I'd choose custom reason with text *"The OP seems to want to build a satellite communication system using only tin cans and string."* ..perhaps it's better that I **cannot** retract the original 'too broad' close note.

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation of the second method:

```
public void setBounds(Rectangle r) {
    setBounds(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
}
```

So to answer your question: They're identical.

Answer (score 1):

> Difference between setBounds(x,y,width,height) and setBounds(new Rectangle(x,y,width,height))

There is no difference in terms of what the methods does. They are just overloaded methods which accept different arguments but performing the same task.

If you check the Java docs:

> **public void setBounds(Rectangle r)**
>
> Sets the bounding Rectangle of this Rectangle to match the specified Rectangle. 
>   This method is included for completeness, to parallel the setBounds method of Component.

---

> **public void setBounds(int x,
>                int y,
>                int width,
>                int height)**
>
> Sets the bounding Rectangle of this Rectangle to the specified x, y, width, and height. 
>   This method is included for completeness, to parallel the setBounds method of Component.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me to understand this.

Comment: You can accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the tick beside the answer.